# Using both Safari and Chrome on an iPad + Google Colab – no copy/paste

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, safari, google-colaboratory, copy-paste

am using iPad air and magic keyboard setup - unable to copy and paste within a cell in google colab, super frustrating.
tried the shortcut menu - but to no avail.
anyone has a solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

actually I found the solution just by trying different key combination.

1.First just pick what you want to copy, you can use touch screen or this key combination:
By clicking shift and arrows you can mark/highlight (when you add to shift+arrow other keys you can speed it up, like:
shift+cmd+left/right [start-end line curosor position]
then shift+up/down arrow [highlight whole line] etc.)

2.When u have your lines chosen (highlighted) you can copy them up or down by this key combination:
shift+alt+up/down arrow

3.When u have it copied and want to move it somewhere else, just stay it highlighted after you copied it and then move it by this key combination:
alt+up/down arrow
This wont reorganize your code, it will swap the lines, so you can pick any place you want your lines to be copied.

Hope it works for you!
For me it works even on Safari without any problems, and when you practice it its actually quite good and easy.