# Cannot copy, cut or paste code in Google Colab (Google Colab + iOS bug)

Tags: ios, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab through Safari (or Google Chrome) on an iPad.

I noticed I cannot cut, copy or paste code from one cell to another on this device. This does not happen on desktop-based operating systems.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679638/using-both-safari-and-chrome-on-an-ipad-google-colab-no-copy-paste) addresses the same issue but is still unsolved and hasn't show any activity in a while. This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1236) addresses the problem too, but all the proposed solutions are workarounds.

Is there a way to fix this? Does anyone know if there's a browser where Colab works as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the bug has been fixed as of 09-17-2021. I can now copy code from one cell to another in Safari on my iPad 8 running iOS 14.7.1.

In case someone needs it, here's the [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1236) on GitHub.